# Getting different results reading from Firebase between iOS simulator and real device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, date

I've met a real problem that I can't understand why it's happens. I'm too beginner to find the problem.

I've got this code :

```
func setPickerFromDataBase(){
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser{
        // user is connect
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        ref.child("Licences").child(userID!).child("Medical").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let classe1 = value?["Classe1"] as? String ?? "1/1/1870"
            let classe2 = value?["Classe2"] as? String ?? "1/1/1870"
            let lapl = value?["LAPL"] as? String ?? "1/1/1870"

            self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
            let updateClasse1 = self.dateFormatter.date(from: classe1) ?? self.dateFormatter.date(from: "01/01/1990")
            let updateClasse2 = self.dateFormatter.date(from: classe2) ?? self.dateFormatter.date(from: "01/01/1990")
            let updateLAPL = self.dateFormatter.date(from: lapl) ?? self.dateFormatter.date(from: "01/01/1990")

            self.calsse1DatePicker.date = updateClasse1!
            self.classe2DatePicker.date = updateClasse2!
            self.laplDatePicker.date = updateLAPL!

            self.setAlert()
        }
    } else {

        fatalError("⛔️ error ...")
    }
}
```

On the simulator iPhone X device with IOS 12.1, everything works as I want.

`updateClasse1` is the firebase Value which is given by `let classe1`.

Same things for `updateClasse2` & `updateLAPL`

But when I send my app to my iPhone X device with iOS 12.1, this returns:

```
classe1 : The value from the dataBase
classe2 : The value from the dataBase
laps : The value from the dataBase 

updateClasse1 :  "01/01/1990"
updateClasse2 :  "01/01/1990"
updateLAPL :  "01/01/1990"
```

I don't know why this happen like that.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same user on both devices?

Comment: Since you are parsing string, make sure that your dates can be parsed with your locale (make sure you have selected the same language and region). F.e. "20/01/1990" would not parse with an "en-US" locale while "01/20/1990" would not parse f.e. with an "es-ES" locale. To make sure you could set the format yourself, f.e to "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: @Daniel thank you very much for you help, I totally forget to set the date format ... My bad ... But now it work very well !!!

Comment: @Daniel That's a super good comment and should be posted as an answer. I'll upvote it and hopefully the OP will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are parsing a string, make sure that your dateFormatter can parse it with the used loale. F.e. `"20/01/1990"` would not parse with an `"en_US"` locale while `"01/20/1990"` would not parse f.e. with an `"es_ES"` locale.

To make sure, you could set the format yourself:

```
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

or make sure that the used locale is the one you are expecting:

```
self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
```